# NMSFTP contentsAtPath returns only a maximum of ~2kB of data

Tags: objective-c, sftp

I'm using an SFTP library, https://github.com/Lejdborg/NMSSH, to connect to an SFTP server. Unfortunately when I try and retrieve the contents of a remote file, the data is clipped at about 2kB.

Here's the code I'm using:

```c
NMSSHSession *session = [NMSSHSession connectToHost:host withUsername:username];
BOOL authenticated = [session authenticateByKeyboardInteractiveUsingBlock:^NSString*(NSString *request) {
    return password;
}];

NMSFTP *sftpSession = [NMSFTP connectWithSession:session];

...

NSData *data = [sftpSession contentsAtPath:remoteFileName];
```

When `remoteFileName` is larger than 2kB, the length of `data` is always 2000.

Does anyone know why this would be the case?

NB: I've tested this on two different SFTP servers, with the exact same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The author of the library fixed the bug (https://github.com/Lejdborg/NMSSH/issues/35)